# Displaying multiple frames of a video element simultaneously

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, three.js

*Some background: graphics newbie here, have just dipped my toes into the world of 3D in the browser with mrdoob's excellent three.js. I intend to go through all the tuts at http://learningwebgl.com/ soon :)*

---

I'd like to know how one would roughly go about re-creating something similar to:
http://yooouuutuuube.com/v/?width=192&height=120&vm=29755443&flux=0&direction=rand

My naive understanding of how yooouuutuuube works is as follows:

1. Create a massive BitmapData (larger than any reasonable browser window size).
2. Determine the number of required rows / columns (across the entire BitmapData plane, not just the visible area) based on the width/height of the target video frame
3. Copy pixels from the most recent video frame to a position on the BitmapData (based on the direction of movement)
4. Iterate through every cell in the BitmapData, copying pixels from the cell that precedes it
5. Scroll the entire BitmapData in the opposite direction to create the illusion of movement, with a Zoetrope-type effect

I'd like to do this in WebGL as opposed to using Canvas so I can take advantage of post-processing using shaders (noise and color channel separation to mimic chromatic aberration).

Here's a screenshot what I have so far:

[image]

- Three videos (same video, but separated into R, G and B channels) are drawn to a canvas 2D context. Each video is slightly offset in order to fake that chromatic aberration look.
- A texture is created in Three.JS which references this canvas. This texture is updated every draw cycle.
- A shader material is created in Three.JS which is linked to a fragment shader (which creates noise / scanlines)
- This material is then applied to a number of 3D Planes.

This works just fine for showing single frames of video, but I'd like to see if I could show multiple frames at once without needing to add additional geometry.

What would be the optimal way of going about such a task? Are there any concepts that I should be studying/investigating in further detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>

            var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
            video.autoplay = true;
            video.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', function ( event ) {

                var scale = 0.5;
                var width = video.videoWidth * scale;
                var height = video.videoHeight * scale;
                var items_total = ( window.innerWidth * window.innerHeight ) / ( width * height );

                for ( var i = 0; i < items_total - 1; i ++ ) {

                    var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;

                    canvas.context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
                    canvas.context.scale( scale, scale );

                    document.body.appendChild( canvas );

                }

                setInterval( function () {

                    var child = document.body.insertBefore( document.body.lastChild, document.body.children[ 1 ] ); // children[ 0 ] == <script>
                    child.context.drawImage( video, 0, 0 );

                }, 1000 / 30 );

            }, false );
            video.src = 'video.ogv';

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I just read the part where say you wanted WebGL for the post processing stuff. Well, this should be a good base I think. Same trick: every frame update only 1 texture, and re-swap all the planes.

Comment: I think I was definitely thinking about things the wrong way — I was hoping to come up with a solution that could be contained in say, a ShaderMaterial, which would then be applied to one PlaneGeometry and that's it. (... is that even possible?) I'll try using what you've given as a base and work with a number of planes instead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobinPyon yes thats possible.